# File Upload Limit Issue in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have fixed my file upload file size as 50MB using the following code 
 
< httpRuntime executionTimeout="60" maxRequestLength="51200"/> in Web.cofig file.
 When i am uploading more than 25MB file it displays error message as "file or directory not found". How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This issue will occur because of timeout reached or IIS upload limit reached.